# how to insert new row at end of the used Range in excel using .net or vba?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vba, excel

I have the range value that contains used range values of excel sheet, now I cant insert row at end of the range area

```
 static public void SpreedsheetOpen(string ExcelFile)
    {
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;        
    }
```

in this xlRange=xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
I get the xl sheet used range value in range object how to insert new row at end of this range.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long

'Select your range
xlRange.Select

'determine the last row of the selection/range
x = Selection.Rows(1).Row
LastRow = Selection.Rows.Count + x - 1

'Select only the last row
Rows(LastRow).Select

'Insert a new row under the selected row
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Comment: xlRange.select means?